# Extracting data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is probably an easy question, but I can't figure it out.
I'm having trouble extracting email and url from this part of a webpage with BeautifulSoup:

```
<!-- ENDE telefonnummer.jsp --></li>
        <li class="email ">
                <a
                    class="link"
                    href="mailto:info@taxi-ac.de"
                    data-role="email-layer"
                    data-template-replacements='{
                        "name": "Aachener-Airport-Taxi Blum",
                        "subscriberId": "128027562762",
                        "captchaBase64": "data:image/jpg;base64,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",
                        "captchaWidth": "110",
                        "captchaHeight": "47",
                        "captchaEncryptedAnswer": "767338fffffff8ffffffd6ffffff8d3038ffffffba1971ffffffdfffffffe3f6c9"
                    }'
                    data-wipe='{"listener":"click","name":"Detailseite E-Mail","id":"128027562762"}'
                >
                    <i class="icon-mail"></i>
                    <span class="text" >info@taxi-ac.de</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <li class="website ">
                <a class="link" href="http://www.aachener-airport-taxi.de" rel="follow" target="_blank" title="http://www.aachener-airport-taxi.de"
                   data-wipe='{"listener":"click","name":"Detailseite Webadresse","id":"128027562762"}'>
                    <i class="icon-website"></i>
                    <span class="text">Zur Website</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get `info@taxi-ac.de` and `http://www.aachener-airport-taxi.de` out of there.
`soup.find(class='email')` obviously doesn't work because `class` makes the compiler think that I want to declare one inside the brackets. While I can use 
`for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))` to get ALL the links in there, I want this specific one. The links are always different, so I can't regex for them, so I guess one would have to navigate through the html-body by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(soup.find("span",{"class":"text"}).text)
print(soup.find(attrs={"class":"website"}).a["href"])
info@taxi-ac.de
http://www.aachener-airport-taxi.de
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. The first method actually returned the phone number instead of the email, because the phone number is nested in a similar structure a few lines above the part of the html body I posted, but I was able to modify it to extract the mail as well :) I'm using `mail = soup.find(attrs={"class":"email"}).a["href"]`, this returns `mailto:info@taxi-ac.de`. You just have to string.split the result and there you go. Probably not the textbook approach, but hey it works.